# Object disappearing after removing Union Boolean

Tags: boolean-modifier

Firstly, sorry for using non-professional terms, I'm a beginner.

I tried using the union boolean on two mesh objects, and it worked properly. Then, I had to remove the boolean, but even though I haven't applied it yet, the red object disappered, and the orange didn't.
It doesn't return when I'm pressing the eye and camera icons next to its name, and when I enter edit mode it still appears.

These are the steps:
I selected the small cube first, then the big one.
[image: Initial Selection]

I pressed Ctrl+Shift+B to open the Bool Tool screen, and chose Brush Boolean - Difference.
Afterwards, The boolean was added to the screen, and the small cube disappeared.

[image]

Then, I removed the modifier but the small cube stayed invisible except for its outline. The camera icon next to its name was off, so I pressed on it but nothing changed.

[image]

Here is how it looks in Edit Mode:

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file or at least show some screenshots? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yeah sure! I added pictures, couldn't add a file.

Answer (score 0):

The small cube is invisible because the *Bool Tool* addon automatically switch the bool tool object to *Display As > Bounds*, switch to *Solid* instead (in the *Object panel > Viewport Display*).

[image]